# iOS - How to show hints for gestures for iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, gestures

I have seen some apps where when you launch them for the first time after downloading (e.g. Chrome app on iPhone), it shows you a list of animated gestures on the screen, kind of giving you a tour of the app.

How do I build one something like that? And how does the app know to launch only for the first time after download and not since then? For the second question, I am guessing a "shown=TRUE" value can be saved inside a PList file and checking the value each time when the app finished launching. But I am more curious about the mechanism involved in creating a guided app tour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transparent and semi-transparent images with a `UIImageView`, so you can make up an image with arrows and notes and put over the whole screen. You could fade it out when the user taps.

To know if it's the first time running the app, you should use `NSUserDefaults` instead of a plist; it's much easier, and you should be app to find a quick tutorial on that fairly easily.

Also, you could check around on [this site](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) for controls like [this one](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/emhint). I haven't used any of them myself, so I'm not sure how much they differ from a regular `UIImageView`. They look nice though.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Didn't realize the simplicity of it.